# Missing Web Parts

Tags: 2010, web-part, content-database

I getting error of missing dependencies on web parts at Central Admin. So I ran Test-ContentDatabase to find all the errors. Once found, I ran another script against my database to find where the missing web parts where. All went well.

The thing is most of the URLs I got don't existe/are not accessible. So I cant navigate and remove the web part of the page.

Is there another approach to delete the web part? I have found scripts online but they all delete straight from the database, which is not recommended.

Central Admin Errors:

> [MissingWebPart] WebPart class [af6b32d9-0e85-924c-cce0-0cae895460f7]
>   is referenced [5] times in the database [SP_PRD_Content], but is
>   not installed on the current farm. Please install any feature/solution
>   which contains this web part. One or more web parts are referenced in
>   the database [SP_PRD_Content], but are not installed on the
>   current farm. Please install any feature or solution which contains
>   these web parts.  [MissingWebPart] WebPart class
>   [666ac2ae-b462-2c71-a04d-324ee783ba43] is referenced [58] times in the
>   database [SP_PRD_Content], but is not installed on the current
>   farm. Please install any feature/solution which contains this web
>   part. One or more web parts are referenced in the database
>   [SP_PRD_ContentL], but are not installed on the current farm.
>   Please install any feature or solution which contains these web parts.

Update:
I managed to find the page where the web part is, but when I navigate to the page's ?contents=1 there is no error web part. Theres actually no web parts displaying however, when I query the database I can find this web part related to the page. 
Do I need to do something to SharePoint realize I've already removed the web part?

Comment: Are you trying to delete a broken webpart on a specific page?

Comment: Yes, this is case 1.  But even after removing from ?contents=1, I still get error. Case 2: I'm trying to delete a webpart on a broken page. The page does not exist, yet health analyzer is displaying an error on it.

Comment: so you can't navigate to it? If you can try appending `?Contents=1` query string to the url.

Comment: I cant. Not even with the ?Contents=1

Comment: Is it possible to delete without navigating to it? :)

Comment: If you have access to server and powershell and know the webpart id it is possible

Comment: I do have both. Can you provide more information on that? Thank you

Comment: @ranbo Could you provide a copy of the errors from Central admin?

Comment: @christoffer added

Comment: Could you please check my update?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the points to troubleshoot it.

- Search with web part name/id in Features folder in 14 hive. If found, you can use [Uninstall-SPFeature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607614.aspx) with Force flag in powershell to remove it. If you have the solution file then install it.
- Install [Feature Admin](https://featureadmin.codeplex.com/) tool and locate the web part. You can remove it in the tool if found.

Comment: I couldn't find it in the folder 14. Its also not a feature, but a web part.

Comment: When health analyzer displays a page that doesn't exist, it means it does exists in content database but can't be viewed in the browser due to number of reasons? Can you open that page in the browser and see the error in the ULS logs and update your question with the error?

Comment: I get page not found(404) and nothing comes up in the ULS logs

Comment: Could you check from the url if the page is coming from any library like pages? If yes, can you see that in powershell?

Comment: They are not in libraries. They are on the root of web or site collection.

Comment: It appears that there is something in the system that's try to access the page and gets 404 not found. I assume that's page is not visible in SharePoint Designer and in Powershell. To troubleshoot that something, you need to enable verbose logging in central admin http://central_admin_url/_admin/metrics.aspx. Then search the page url in the log files. You may need to search the last part of the url as sometimes the url in the log files appears with port. Example http://site:80/page.aspx. Please beware this would create some heavy log files.

Comment: Could you please check my update?

Comment: @ranbo, do you have access to old SharePoint server 2007? If yes, please go to 12/template/features directory and search id `af6b32d9-0e85-924c-cce0-0cae895460f7` in all folders and files. If you find one, copy that folder and paste on the current SharePoint 14/template/features directory. Try activating this feature using powershell and run the test again. You may need to copy the relevant webpart assembly as well. Please update your question with the xml contents if you find one with that id.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this via powershell, modify it where necessary:

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

$siteUrl = "http://SharePoint/sites/projects/testproject1"
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteUrl -ErrorAction Stop

#Declare the absolute path to the SharePoint page
$pagePath = "/SitePages/Home.aspx"
$pageUrl = $siteUrl + $pagePath
write-host "Processing site: ", $siteUrl
write-host "Processing page: ", $pageUrl

#Initialise the Web part manager for the specified profile page.
$spWebPartManager = $spWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageUrl, 
[System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

#List all the Webparts in the specified page
foreach ($webpart in $spWebPartManager.WebParts)
{
    write-host $siteUrl +": Existing Web part - " + $webpart.Title + " : " + $webpart.ID
    break;
}
#Remove the Share Documents Web part from that page
foreach ($webpart in ($spWebPartManager.WebParts | Where-Object {$_.Title -
eq "Shared Documents"}))
{
    write-host $siteUrl +": Existing Web part - " + $webpart.Title + " : " + $webpart.ID
    $webpart1 = $webpart
    break;
}
#Delete the existing webpart
$spWebPartManager.DeleteWebPart($spWebPartManager.WebParts[$webpart1.ID])
write-host "Deleted the existing Shared Document web part."

$spWeb.Dispose()
```

Source: http://surya20p.blogspot.ca/2012/11/remove-webpart-from-sharepoint-pages.html